# After login sending ResendRequest

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

My client fix engine connecting to server fix engine using quickfix4j.

Server fix engine running Sunday 1 am to Friday 5 pm .

This is my initiator configuration

```
    [default]
    FileStorePath=some path
    ConnectionType=initiator
    SocketConnectHost=remoteserver
    StartTime=00:00:00
    EndTime=00:00:00
    HeartBtInt=30
    ReconnectInterval=10
    ResetOnDisconnect=N
    ResetOnLogout=N
    ResetOnLogon=N
    SocketUseSSL=Y
    ForceResync=Y

    [session]
    BeginString=FIX.4.4
    SocketConnectPort=9878
    SenderCompID=TestSender
    TargetCompID=TestTarget
    SendRedundantResendRequests=N
    UseDataDictionary=Y
    DataDictionary=FIX44.xml
    SessionName=TRADING
    ValidateUnorderedGroupFields=N
    ValidateIncomingMessage=N
```

My session logout at 19:00: EST(That is 00:00:00 UTC). This is correct.

Again client fix engine send login request and get the login response from server. Immediately after login response I see the resendRequest my fix engine is making(35=2).

I observed that my login request 35=A has the sequence number 0 but server result is much higher.

Due to this client fix engine sending ResendRequest.

DO I need to update my configuration to fix this issue?

Comment: Find out what your counterparty expects you to do with sequence numbers on logout/login, and tweak your `ResetOnLogout` appropriately. I would expect you to have `ResetOnLogout` to equal `Y`

Comment: Agree with you. I will check for it.

Comment: You are best to start a new StackOverflow question for a new question rather than edit it in your current question. It gets too chaotic otherwise.

Comment: Done. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: FYI, it's "QuickFIX/J" not "quickfix4j".  I corrected your title.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Any luck with the hint I gave?

Comment: ResetOnLogout is not supported by the server fix engine. But they asked to use the ResetOnLogon=Y but in that case we will not able to request the resendMessages.  I am making the client session same as server session(week long), so that there will not be sequence reset in middle week and in case of any disconnection we can request resend message. I guess that would be best approach.

Comment: Resend messages is not something you need to do yourself, the session layer of QuickFix will do that if it is required by the FIX protocol (ie gaps in message sequence ID). Also: read [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) on Meta.StackExchange on comments. I was not informed of your comment as you didn't start your comment with `@TT`.

Comment: @TT : You are correct. Resend request is not done manually. But when we have daily session and server has week long session, sequence mismatch get detected at start of each client session(sequence reset to zero). This leads to resend message. I would take care of the replies by using @.

Comment: Good luck with your setup mate =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Start/EndTime and Start/EndDay should always match the ones on the server-side.